# HTML5 Download with javascript onlick combined

Tags: javascript, php, database, html, file

I'm using the following code to force download of mp3 file

```
<a id="download" href="http://locationtomp3file.mp3" download>Start Download</a>
```

Above code does the download smoothly. However, I want to track the number of downloads and update the database row for that song. Adding onclick doesn't work unless my  attribute have **href="#"**. Any work around or suggestions?

Comment: I forget to mention that this version of my website is only for all android users. Out of many methods to download a file, I found this to be the only perfectly working method that force download on all android browsers. I have 1 other method to download using javascript and create blob link, but the issue is that the file downloads in background then appear once completed. This will take time for large files and will confuse the users that the download button isnt working.

Comment: you're going to need ajax for this if you want to use JS. Your question is short on code/detail. If you want to track, then you need to `UPDATE table SET col_x = col_x +1 WHERE col_y = ?` as an example. A force download method with a header will also need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're in control of the back-end. I would just count the GET entries of your http server for that particular file. I think it is better because it is asynchronous, and prevents accurate count (if you use ajax, and the ajax request fails, you'll miss one count)

It's as simple as `grep "locationtomp3file.mp3" /var/log/http/access_log | wc -l` in redhat/apache2 environment. Run that every once and then on your server and update your database with the result, that's how I'd do it. You might not be aware of it but it's actually very good and very healthy to have a number of tasks running as batches in the background, in "offline" mode. You can run them as often as every 5 minutes if you'd like - as long as they are not resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="download" href="#" download>Start Download</a>

<!-- With Jquery -->
<script>
$("#download").click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://locationtomp3file.mp3';
});
</script>
```